# Parse Open Server allow NoSQL injections

Tags: ionic-framework, parse-platform, nosql, parse-server, nosql-injection

Or does it have protections in place against this?

I'm using parse and saw a potential NoSQL injection flagged and want to be sure this can't be done and there are protections. I'm also using MongoDB. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you see that ?

Comment: Curious as well, if you have a security related disclosure to make, use the appropriate channels as described in the main parse-server repository.